# OS becomes unresponsible, when doing heavy processing

Tags: 18.04, performance, cpu

I use my machine (**HP EliteBook 850 G5**) for programming. Unfortunately I have the problem, that when I screw up somehow (e.g. creating an infinite loop, making an expensive db-query, and so on), my whole machine freezes.
It becomes barely responsive. When I move the mouse I have a movement every few seconds. So it's ridiculously slow.
When this happens, I try to go to another console (Ctrl+Alt+F2), and kill the process which causes the freeze. It's very slow, but it works.

My question:
**Can I somehow resereve some of the processing power of my machine for the OS?**
As a matter of fact I know that the Playstation OS does something like this. No matter how bad the game is coded and how often it crashes (Cyberpunk), the User Interface is always fully accessible. Can I do this somehow with my PC? E.g. reserve one core only for the OS?

```
uname -a
Linux Michael-PC 5.4.0-66-generic #74~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 11:17:31 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

For programming I mainly use:

- Ruby (Rubymine as IDE)
- Docker
- Postgres

---

### Thank you all for your comments!

Hardware:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8350U CPU @ 1.70GHz
16 GB RAM
SSD: 256GB Model: SK hynix BC501 HFM256GDJTNG-8310A
```

@heynnema

```
free -h
              total      used       free     shared    buff/cache   available
Mem:         15G         10G        421M        2,1G        4,8G        2,9G
Swap:        975M        975M         72K



grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0



sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

I guess you guys found the issue... The swap is a bit low, isn't it? 1.5 times the size if the RAM? lol, i got `1/16`

Comment: Please [edit] your question by adding hardware specs of your machine (amount of memory, CPU model, disk types and models, etc.).

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV.

Comment: Sounds like you have a couple of causes for the slowdown: cpu maxes out (in a loop), or running short of memory(db query?).  schedtool package allows you to associate CPU cores with processes.  the "nice" command can reduce a process's likelyhood of being activated (so others may run).  Adding swap may help with some problems, adding memory almost always helps.  There are even real-time kernels, to allow better control of things that need to be responsive.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thank you all! @heynnema - I have added the output that you have asked.

Comment: Yes, your swap is too low. I'd make it 4G. But since you're using LVM, it's partition-based, instead of /swapfile based. Although I can't guide you, you'll have to expand the /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 partition... probably using `gparted` or LVM CLI tools. Type `man lvm` or `man lvm2` to get more info.